# Anchoring ink to text

Tags: onenote

Is there any way to anchor ink to a body of text? For example, I circle a word, and highlight some others:
[image]

Then if I add a header, it will leave the ink inplace and shift the text down:
[image]

How do I get the ink to follow the body of text down (or up)?

Comment: This isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't. Sadly, OneNote doesn't support ink anchoring at this point. Please feel free to upvote the feature here:

https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/327186-onenote-for-windows-windows-phone/suggestions/6355217-group-objects-and-anchor-ink-to-text-and-images